# how can I create child model conditions on ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

```
class Invoice < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :purchase
end

class Purchase < ApplicationRecord
  has_many   :invoices
end
```

Invoice has, boolean "paid" columns.

since it has_many, sometime invoice record may be more than 1.
I would like to search "all paid", or "partial paid", or "not paid" purchase record.
if invoice records are 3, one of them is paid, it means "partial paid"

how could I make this condition with ApplicationRecord?

I tried like this

```
joins(:invoices).where("invoices.paid": true)
```

but it also returns partial paid records.

Comment: Protip: use a datetime `paid_at` column instead to kill two birds with one stone.

Answer (score 0):

Since `paid` is a boolean field here, it holds either true or false value.

If you have another field(probably `payment_status`) in `Invoice` table that should identify the record as "Fully Paid", "Partially Paid", "Not Paid". Then the query would be:

```
Purchase.joins(:invoice).where(invoices: {paid: true, payment_status: "Fully Paid"})  # `paid: true` could be omitted
```

As a best practice you can define a scope:

```
class Purchase < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :invoices
  scope    :paid_invoices, -> { joins(:invoice).where(invoices: {payment_status: "Fully Paid"}) }
end
```

Comment: Maybe my explanation was misleading.

if there are 3 records that belongs to one purchase,

invoice1 is paid true
invoice2 is paid true
invoice3 is paid false


in this case, from purchase point of view, "partial paid"


invoice1 is paid true
invoice2 is paid true
invoice3 is paid true

in this case, "partial paid"

So I would like to make condition


```
class Purchase < ApplicationRecord
  scope :paid_invoices, -> { joins(:invoice) ????  }
  scope :unpaid_invoices, -> { joins(:invoice) ????  }
  scope :partial_paid_invoices, -> { joins(:invoice) ????  }
end